# Heyting's Definition of Spreads and Species

Tags: foundations, philosophy

I was reading "Intuitionism - an Introduction, A. Heyting" but I could not understand his definitions of "species" and "spreads" (and also there is a thing which he calls "ips"?).

As I understand, "species" and "spreads" are two different types of sets, but I am having a little bit trouble following the book.

Is there anyone who are -or willing to be- familiar with Heyting's book, and can say something about these notions?

As an example, book says:

3.1.2. Definition of a Spread

A $spread$ $M$ is defined by two laws; the first, which I shall call the $spread-law$ $\Lambda_M$, regulates the choices of natural numbers, while the effect of the second or $complementary$ $law$ $\Gamma_M$ is to assign a sequence of mathematical entities to any ips of natural numbers which is generated according to the first law.

Comment: Ips, page 32: Infinitely proceeding sequence.

Comment: See [Intuitionistic Mathematics: Lawless sequences](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/#LawSeq) and see Anne Troelstra, [Choice Sequences: A Chapter of Intuitionistic Mathematics- (Clarendon, 1977)](https://books.google.it/books/about/Choice_Sequences.html?id=GcSEAAAAIAAJ)

Comment: Troelstra, page 2: "A mathematical object will be called "lawlike" if it is a complete construction, something we can describe completely. The two principal kinds of lawlike objects are natural numbers and lawlike functions of natural numbers." Page 12: "We think of a lawless sequence (of natural numbers) as a process (not a law!) of assigning values to the arguments $0,1,2,\ldots$; at any stage, only finitely many values (i.e. an initial segment) of the sequence are known."

Comment: Pag.7: "Lawlike sequences are completely determined by a law given in advance. The concept of choice sequence generalizes the concept of lawlike function. The simplest concept of *choice sequence* is that of a lawless sequence."

Comment: A *species* is the intuitionistic equivalent of a set of (mathematical) objects. A sequence (lawlike and lawless) is a mapping from $\mathbb N$ to a species $X$, i.e. a process that associates with every natural number a mathematical object belonging to species $X$.